Request header field istest is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response in Codeigniter 3
I am using Codeigniter 3. I created an API builder application, and there is an external website that wants to use the API that has been created in the API builder, let's call it portal.
I created a JavaScript called global-ajax.js to call the API in the portal project like this
// ajax-global.js
const url = 'https://webserver.or.id/api/1.0/getSiswa';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(request) {
          request.setRequestHeader("api_access_key", "xxxxxx"); // Ganti dengan API key Anda
          request.setRequestHeader("web_origin", "https://portal.or.id/");
    },
    success: function(response) {
        // Tampilkan data siswa di console
        console.log('Data Siswa:', response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#output').val('Error: ' + textStatus + '\n' + errorThrown);
    }
});

When I look through the console, this error appears,

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://webserver.or.id/api/1.0/getSiswa' from origin 'https://portal.or.id' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field web_origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

How can I get rid of the error and make the portal able to access the API created in the API builder (web server)?
Because, in the API builder controller, the requirement to be able to access the API is by providing api_access_key and web_origin for authentication.
Here is one function in the API controller (api-builder project)
private function isAuthorized()
{
    $headers = getallheaders();
    error_log(print_r($headers, true));  // Log header yang diterima

    $api_key = $headers['api_access_key'] ?? '';
    $website_origin = $headers['web_origin'] ?? '';

    error_log("API Key: $api_key, Website Origin: $website_origin");  // Log nilai API Key dan Website Origin

    if (empty($api_key) || empty($website_origin)) {
        return false;
    }

    $is_key_valid = $this->M_api->validate_api_key($api_key, $website_origin);
    error_log("Is Key Valid: " . ($is_key_valid ? 'true' : 'false'));  // Log hasil validasi

    return $is_key_valid;
}

